# How to hide "Phone is plugged in and battery is fully charged" icon

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Well this is my first Windows Phone 8 app.

On my all pages I set  `shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False"` to show the app always on full screen mode. But when I'm showing a message box a

> Phone is plugged in and battery is fully charged

icon is showing. Please see below image.

[image]

I want this to be hidden when a message box is displaying.

Comment: Um, no.  That's not yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know, there is no such possibility in the public API.

Only API for OEM.